# What is the correct way to make calls among flask-restful endpoints in a flask API?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm setting up an API REST with flask-restful. I have not found any documentation nor examples of how an internal call among endpoints would be done. Said otherway, I want to consume one of the endpoints from inside the implementation of other endpoint.

I could treat it like an usual external call to another API but I feel like I would be commiting a crime against good practices somehow

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, version='1.0', title='FooTitle',
          description='FooDescription', )
ns_conf = api.namespace('FooName', description='FooDescription')


# Endpoint 1
@ns_conf.route('/endpoint1')
class MyResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return 'Hello '


# Endpoint 2
@ns_conf.route('/endpoint2')
@api.doc(params={'your_name': 'Your name'})
class greeting(Resource):
    def get(self):
        # Transfer request parameters to variables:
        your_name= request.args.get('your_name')
        # I WOULD LIKE TO GET THE OUTPUT OF ENDPOINT 1 here:
        hello = call_endpoint_1()
        return hello + str(your_name)
```

What is the correct way to implement 'call_endpoint_1()'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply: factor out the common part into a plain function and call it from both endpoints:

```
def say_hello():
    return "Hello "

@ns_conf.route('/endpoint1')
class MyResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return say_hello()


# Endpoint 2
@ns_conf.route('/endpoint2')
@api.doc(params={'your_name': 'Your name'})
class greeting(Resource):
    def get(self):
        # Transfer request parameters to variables:
        your_name= request.args.get('your_name')
        # I WOULD LIKE TO GET THE OUTPUT OF ENDPOINT 1 here:
        hello = say_hello()
        return hello + str(your_name)
```